# Ruby - Using Comparable mixin to compare objects on two different attributes

Tags: ruby, comparable

Is there an easy way (i.e. using the spaceship operator) to define comparison in Ruby based on two different attributes? I.e. If I have a class that contains two attributes, attr1 and attr2, is there a Rubyesque way of comparing two instances of this class on attr1, and if they're equal then compare them on attr2?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html?

Comment: it's easy to overload the spaceship operator (just add `def <=>(other) ... end`) but you have to figure out a schema how to compare these two instances. Let's say you want to compare instance a with instance b (based on attr1 and attr2): 1. when is a > b ? 2. when is a == b ? 3. when is a < b?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of the comparable mixin is to provide a definition for the spaceship (comparison) operator. So if you want to do a comparison across two attributes, then do it. Here's an overly verbose example:

```
def <=>(obj)
  comparison = self.attr1 <=> obj.attr1

  if comparison == 0
    return self.attr2 <=> obj.attr2
  else
    return comparison
  end
end
```

Obviously the above assumes `attr1`, and `attr2` both have definitions for the spaceship operator. As well you'll need to determine what constitutes greater than, and less than, which is likely a bit difficult across two attributes. Which suggests that comparable may not be the proper code for your scenario.

---

A more succinct and idiomatic way of writing this would be:

```
def <=>(obj)
  self.attr1 <=> obj.attr1 == 0 ? self.attr2 <=> obj.attr2 : self.attr1 <=> obj.attr1
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the kind of thing I was looking for

Comment: What would be a more concise formulation? One using the ternary operator?

Comment: @N.N. yes. `comparison == 0 ? self.attr2 <=> obj.attr2 : comparison` which could be reduced further into a single statement by inlining the `comparison` variable.

Comment: If that is a more idiomatic example of such a function your answer would be better if it included it.

Comment: @N.N. agreed. Given the nature of the question, the questioner would likely have not understood the idiomatic answer. However, it's worth adding it in. Thanks for the suggestion! :D

Answer (score 16):

This is an easily extendible (to more attributes) way:

```
def <=>(other)
  [self.attr1, self.attr2] <=> [other.attr1, other.attr2]
end
```

Comment: This dosen't work for me. My solution is exactly the same as Gavin Miller and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

### Spaceship with 'not comparable'

#### [Spaceship requires:](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Comparable.html)

```
a <=> b :=
  if a < b then return -1
  if a = b then return  0
  if a > b then return  1
  if a and b are not comparable then return nil  <= I wanted this
```

Steenslag's solution wasn't giving me the nil when 'not comparable'.

#### Impementation

Added extra line for coping with 'not comparable':

```
def <=> other
  return nil unless other.is_a?(self.class)
  [self.attr1, self.attr2] <=> [other.attr1, other.attr2]
end
```